# mySql insert needs all columns noted

Tags: mysql

I recently started hosting my own site and mySQL db.  Everything works fine, but whenever I do an insert or update to any of tables, it errors out if I do not call out each and every column.  Is there a setting for the table or the DB that controls this?  I never had to do this with my previous DB host.

Thanks.

Comment: check the privelage for the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to write an `INSERT` query.

1. `INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)`
2. `INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, ...) SELECT ...`
3. `INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (val1, val2, ...)`
4. `INSERT INTO tablename SELECT ...`

In the first two methods, you don't have to list all the columns, since you specify the columns to be filled in explicitly. The columns that aren't in the `(col1, col2, ...)` list will get their default values.  The `VALUES` list or the `SELECT` query must return as many columns as you specified in the list.

In methods 3 and 4, MySQL requires the `VALUES` list or the `SELECT` query to return as many columns as the table contains, and they must be in the same order as the table definition. I can't find any setting that disables the column count check in these methods.

In methods 1 and 3, you can put the keyword `DEFAULT` in place of any of the column values to insert its default value.

If your server is in `STRICT` mode, you also have to explicitly set any columns that do not have a `DEFAULT` option in the schema. If it's not in strict mode, automatic defaults will be used.

Comment: I am using the first example that you give:    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO NFLclubs (clubname,clubmembers) Values ('$C','$N')",$db);
  if( !$result ) {die("Error updating entry."); }

Comment: See the addition I just made about `STRICT` mode.

Comment: That was it.  I disabled strict mode and everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn't fail if you UPDATE the values of some, but not all, columns in particular rows.

When you create your table, you need to set a default value for each column which you may choose to omit in your INSERT statements.